# How to use jQuery to change the background color of a textbox?

Tags: jquery, background-color

How to use jQuery to change the backgound color of a textbox?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445711/jquery-mobile-set-textbox-background

Answer (score 45):

Better practice is to seperate UI from logic, in your case:

```
$("#textboxid").addClass("aClass");
```

---

If you really need it your way, then do the following:

```
$("#textboxid").css({"background-color": "color"});
```

Replace `#textboxid` with the desired selector, and color with the desired color.

Note the following does the same for one property:

```
$("#textboxid").css("background-color", "color");
```

Comment: No need for hard coded presentation in js. Use Css for style, js for behaviour.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#txtBoxID').css('background-color', '#ffff00');
```

Answer (score 8):

Better to add a class name to the input rather than hard coding styles into your js. 
Presentation styles should reside in css not js.

```
$('#inputId').addClass('someCssClass');
```

Comment: And that is also what your are doing now. I would say you should add an semantic class, not backgroundRed, I see that as an antipattern. And maybe the code here is UI code.

Comment: it was just a sample....of course you should not have classes for each color. geee

Comment: You still should not hard code style into js. What happens when he wants a border, then a different font. End up with an ugly mess of js.

Comment: Ah, you modified the example.

But for UI JS can it be appropriate.

Comment: js for behaviour, not for adding css. Why make it more difficult that addClass?

Comment: The "why" is the semantic portion right?  so `addClass('highlight');` would be an appropriate thing for javascript to do, and then the stylesheet would specify what that looks like.    Now, you could replace "highlight" with any random description, but the function is the same.

Comment: But your original answer showed none of these thoughts. Now your the expert;)

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, don't use jQuery. I assume you want to do this on focus or on blur, so you can do:

```css
#textboxid {background-color:defaultcolor;}
#textboxid:focus {background-color:selectedcolor;}
```