# Jquery Mobile - set textbox background

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, background, textbox

I'm trying to set background color the `JQuery Mobile` textbox field, however the background is not covering the whole textbox. As you can see in the image below on the left and the right ends of the control there are parts that are not inheriting the background color.

[image: enter link description here]

**The problem**

The problem is that `JQuery Mobile` is adding dynamically some `div` wrappers and the textbox is rendered like that

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="inputreq ui-input-text ui-body-c" id="name" value="">
</div>
```

If I set the background color to the `div` wrapper it will cover the whole textbox, but how can I do this with pure `CSS`? Is there a way to set the style of an element's parent?

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqSzw/) with the example above. Is there a brave JQM warrior that could help me?

Comment: CSS `div.ui-inpux-text { your style here }` But this will override all input types except for `type=search`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VqSzw/2/

Comment: @Omar You are right, but I don't want this to happen, since I want only required fields to have a background.

Comment: Then your only way is to do it programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I can see, there is no CSS parent selector, so my be you are right and the only solution would be the one that @PiLHA posted earlier.

Comment: you can use `$('.required').closest('div').css('background', 'red');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```css
.ui-shadow-inset, ui-corner-all, ui-btn-shadow, ui-body-c
{
   background-color: #D5EEFF !important;
}
```

If this override some other component, remove the award this CSS.

**UPDATE**

```js
$(".inputreq").parent().css("background-color", "#D5EEFF");
```

[jQuery workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/VqSzw/1/)

Comment: This workaround won't help me - the reason is that I want to set the background color only on the required fields, not on all of the fields. Also in you solution how can I distinct between required field and a regular one - I'm finishing with the same problem as at the moment, since the CSS class I've set on a control is still inside a div wrapper added by JQM.

Comment: I understand your problem. See if this other solution can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This may help, but I'd prefer a pure CSS solution. I'll wait to see if there are any other suggestions.

Comment: No problem, if you find the solution post it. Good luck.